# How to traverse a Monad with recursion definition and collect the results?

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads, monad-transformers

I implement the monad transformer `MaybeT`.

```
newtype MaybeT m a =
    MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

Then, I write a monad for backtracking.

```
newtype BackT m a =
    BackT { unBackT :: MaybeT m (a, BackT m a) }
```

Here,`Back m a` has recursion definition.

---

In my mind, there are isomorphisms.

```
                 unBackT
BackT m a <-------------------> MaybeT m (a, BackT m a)
            BackT(constructor)    

                              runMaybeT
MaybeT m (a, BackT m a) <------------------> m (Maybe (a, BackT m a))
                         MaybeT(constructor)
```

Thus, I actually get something like

```
m (Just(1, m (Just(2, m (Just(3, m (Just(4, Nothing))))))))
```

In the example given above, there are 4 computations(Monad is computation?). I need something called `runBackT` to collect them using `[]`.

Thanks for the answer from @rampion , and I remove some meaningless questions.

- <del>What is the type of results? It should be something depending on `m`.</del> (Answer: The type of results should be `m a`.)
- <del>How to collect all results? Is it possible?</del> (Answer: Monad `m a` does not guarantee to have a way to get an "unwrapped" type.)
- How to collect all arguments like 1, 2, 3, 4 in example. It's type should be `[a]`. Does such a `BackT m a -> [a]` function exist? Or, can we only get `m [a]`? (Answer:Only `BackT m a -> m [a]` **might** exist.)

---

**Update**

Monad can be divided into two classes: "opened monads" (like `[]`, `Maybe`) and "closed monads" (like `IO`). The "opened monads" have functions with type `m a -> b` to open them. e.g.

```
showMaybe :: (Show a) => Maybe a -> String
showMaybe mx = case mx of
    Nothing -> "Nothing"
    Just x -> show x
```

1. How to implement `(Monad m, Show m) => BackT m a -> [String]`?
2. More generally, `Monad m => (m a -> b) -> BackT m a -> [b]`?
3. Under what conditions, does `Monad m => BackT m a -> [m a]` exist? `BackT m a` sequences computations `m a` recursive by cross-recursive definition. How to change it into iteration `[m a]`? If it exists, how to implement it? We can map `m a -> b` to `[m a]`, and question (2) will be solved.
4. `Monad m => (m a -> a) -> BackT m a -> m [a]`? Just wrap the result of question(2) by constructor `m`.

Therefore, the key point is question (3).

The most difficult part for me is recursion definition of `BackT m a`. I'd appreciate it if you could show the implement or share some advice.

Answers only for question (3) is OK.

---

**Update**

Thanks for comments from @rampion, the [`ListT` from list-t package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-1.0.1/docs/ListT.html#v:ListT) answered my questions.

Comment: fyi `BackT` is isomorphic to [`ListT` from the `list-t` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-1.0.1/docs/ListT.html#v:ListT)

Comment: to be pedantic, you're missing some parentheses. `m Maybe (a, BackT m a)` should be `m (Maybe (a, BackT m a))` and `m Just(1, m Just(2, m Just(3, m Just(4, Nothing))))` should be `m (Just(1, m (Just(2, m (Just(3, m (Just(4, Nothing))))))))`

Comment: @rampion Thank you. I shall correct it.

Comment: @rampion Thanks for your mentioned `ListT`. It solved the problem completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to collect all arguments like `1, 2, 3, 4` in example. It's type should be `[a]`. Does such a `BackT m a -> [a]` function exist? Or we can only get `m [a]`?

Think of this the other way around first.

We can certainly get a `BackT m a` value for any `Monad m`:

```
Prelude> emptyBackT = BackT (MaybeT (return Nothing))
Prelude> :t emptyBackT
emptyBackT :: Monad m => BackT m a
```

And with the power of `fmap`, we can convert any `m a` to
a `BackT m a` for any `Functor m`:

```
Prelude> lift ma = BackT (MaybeT (fmap (\a -> Just (a, emptyBackT)) ma))
Prelude> :t lift
lift :: Monad m => m a -> BackT m a
```

So if we had a way to convert any `BackT m a -> [a]`, we could combine that with `lift` to get `m a -> [a]` for any `Functor m`!

But we know we can't do that in Haskell. Some functors (like `[]` or `Maybe`) unwrapped, but there's others (like `IO`) that can't.

So `runBackT` needs to have type `BackT m a -> m [a]`.

As for implementation, here's some leading questions.

You've got an isomorphism from `BackT m a` to  `m (Maybe (a, BackT m a))`, so

- Assuming `runBackT :: BackT m a -> m [a]` were already implemented, could you implement `consBackT :: a -> BackT m a -> m [a]`?
- Assuming `runBackT :: BackT m a -> m [a]` were already implemented, could you implement `unwrapBackT :: Maybe (a, BackT m a) -> m [a]`?
- Assuming `unwrapBackT :: Maybe (a, BackT m a) -> m [a]` were already implemented, could you implement `innerToList :: m (Maybe (a, BackT m a)) -> m [a]`?

(Hint: the types I've used in the leading questions are incomplete)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your proof is very clear. Now I know only monads like `[]` and `Maybe` can be unwrapped. (e.g. They are instances of `Show`)

Comment: The leading questions you mentioned is quite difficult for me. I need more research on it. From my point of view, the key point is whether computation `m a` can be changed from recursion order to iteration. The cross-recursive definition of `m` and `BackT m a` might make it impossible, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your mentioned `ListT`, which should be the answer of my questions.